# Vim function to check if text exists in a file

Tags: vim

I would like to see if something already exists in the current file (e.g. a certain import) by making a custom Vim function. Just an idea, is it possible to use the response from searching for something with `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`search()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#search()). Specifying `'nw'` in flags (second argument); `n` will ensure the cursor stays in place, and `w` ensures you search the *whole* file, not just a portion of it. You can then check the function's result; if it's non-zero, then something matched your pattern.